# Lightest Third Party SDK for Chat(Group and one to one chats) in android

Tags: android, chat

I am trying to search for chat SDK(android) to embed chat feature in my app. So i found some of the sdk but they are very heavy 1MB approx. This will add up to the app size.

Question : needed a chat sdk in android but with smaller sdk size. Can anyone suggest some name?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Quickblox](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android), If you use only Chat feature i.e.(Core, messages & chat) and implement a chat, in your project it will cost your app 2~3mb.

Libraries are in the form of jar, For chat you need to use these,

**quickblox-android-sdk-core.jar** (contains core, auth and users classes) **371kb**

**quickblox-android-sdk-chat.jar** (contains chat class) **1mb**

**quickblox-android-sdk-messages.jar** (contains messages class) push notifications **70kb**

Comment: i want it to be less than 1 mb. 2~3mb will be too much.

Comment: 2~3mb i mentioned is the final size of your apk

Comment: Ok! quickblox i checked there sdk it is not less than 1mb. i need all of these jars(push notification, chat, auth classes). So, that is why i am asking for any other chat sdk with lesser size.